# Android: Get the image source name of an ImageView to display on a TextView

Tags: android

Hi I am new into android development and I am having trouble into this one. I wanted to display the src name of my `imageView` on a `textView` when I click a certain Image.
To understand much further here is my hardcode for the `image clickListener` (hope someone can also help me to improve my coding).

```
    int ctr = 0;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play);

        //DECLARE CLICK LISTENERS ON OBJECTS
        ImageView ImageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageView ImageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
        ...

public void onClick(View v) {
        //CHANGE TEXT VIEW TEXT BASED ON THE CTR VALUE
        TextView TextView1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

        //I WANT TO CHANGE THIS ONE TO DISPLAY SRC INSTEAD OF THE CTR VALUE
        TextView1.setText(Integer.toString(ctr)); 
}
```

There, instead of displaying the ctr value I wanted to display the src name of whatever image I click between the two images I set. I believe it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: you are displaying img from drawable folder or from any other resoures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below method for get name of resource from it's id:

```
/**
         * Determines the Name of a Resource,
         * by passing the <code>R.xyz.class</code> and
         * the <code>resourceID</code> of the class to it.
         * @param aClass : like <code>R.drawable.class</code>
         * @param resourceID : like <code>R.drawable.icon</code>
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if field is not found.
         * @throws NullPointerException if <code>aClass</code>-Parameter is null.                  
         * <code>String resName = getResourceNameFromClassByID(R.drawable.class, R.drawable.icon);</code><br>
         * Then <code>resName</code> would be '<b>icon</b>'.*/
        public String getResourceNameFromClassByID(Class<?> aClass, int resourceID)
                                                throws IllegalArgumentException{
                /* Get all Fields from the class passed. */
                Field[] drawableFields = aClass.getFields();

                /* Loop through all Fields. */
                for(Field f : drawableFields){
                        try {
                                /* All fields within the subclasses of R
                                 * are Integers, so we need no type-check here. */

                                /* Compare to the resourceID we are searching. */
                                if (resourceID == f.getInt(null))
                                        return f.getName(); // Return the name.
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                /* Throw Exception if nothing was found*/
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
```

For Example of use :

```
String resName = getResourceNameFromClassByID(R.drawable.class, R.drawable.icon);
```

Result will be `icon`

Comment: @if you get your solution than give vote up and click this answer as right

Answer (score 21):

in xml you can add tag to set any information with image

### Example

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageview1" 
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:tag="bg"/>
```

Dynamically you can use `imageView.setTag("any name")` to set any data along with image and `imageView.getTag()` to retrieve image information

```
String backgroundImageName = (String) imageView.getTag();
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help.

Answer (score -1):

**try this**

```
  String resName = getResourceNameFromClassByID(R.drawable.class, R.drawable.imagename);
```

Comment: have u test this code Please upload code how to do this