# pass list view image from one activity to next activity in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, xml-parsing, android-listview

I have developed one Android application.

The app is performing displayed list view using xml parsing.

I have used below code. The text data is pass from one activity to next activity successfully but the image doesn't pass from one activity to another activity.

How can I pass image from one activity to the next activity in Android application?

This is first activity:

```
String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
String duration = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration)).getText().toString();
String artist = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
String image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getImageMatrix().toString();
// Starting new intent
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, duration);
in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, image);
startActivity(in);
```

This is next activity:

```
Intent in = getIntent();

// Get XML values from previous intent
String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
String duration = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);
String artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
Bitmap bitmap =(Bitmap) in.getParcelableExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
// Displaying all values on the screen
TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_label);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
lblName.setText(title);
lblCost.setText(duration);
lblDesc.setText(artist);
```

**EDIT:**

I have changed the first activity like below code:

```
String image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getImageMatrix().toString();
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, image);
```

I have changed the second activity like below:

```
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "Image";
String Image = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
ImageView thumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_label);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(Image, thumb);
```

After I have to run the app means I am getting empty image only.

Comment: how are the images prepared for the listview? if all the data in your listview is already ordered on the device, perhaps you could just pass the position to your activity then act on that.

Comment: you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463243/android-get-the-image-source-name-of-an-imageview-to-display-on-a-textview for passing images between Activity

Comment: @user1855914 Please see my answer may be it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For passing Image between acitivities first convert your image into bitmap then pass that bitmap to next activity using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890405/1405983).

Comment: hi already i have tried this tutorial.it is doesn't helpful for me.please read my update question and give em solution for this.

Comment: when you passed image from first activity check image have values or not ??

Comment: @user1855914 : why u are trying to pass whole image instead of just URI of Image  ?

Comment: i have selected particular product on my first activity means i have to display that particular image only.but i got the no_image.png image only .

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap cannot be passed through the intent directly instead you will have to convert the bitmap into byte array and then transfer the byte array through intent and in called activity convert the byte array into bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),"Image ID");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
```

Then passing the image

```
            intent.putExtra("imagepass", bytes.toByteArray());
             startActivity(intent);
```

Then on called activity

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("imagepass");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

    ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvw2);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```